# Build-automation - sbt: Compile/Test against multiple dependencies

Tags: scala, maven, build-automation, sbt, guava

We just published parts of our library ([Mango](https://github.com/feijoas/mango)) which is a Scala wrapper around [Google Guava](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Guava) common libraries for Java.

The library currently depends on Google Gauva 14.0, but we would like to add support for other versions as well.

Is there a way in [sbt](http://www.scala-sbt.org/), a build-automation tool for Scala and Java projects, to create maven like profiles, where each profile compiles against a different version of the respective Guava dependency, so we can include it in the continuous integration test matrix?

Ideally, it should be possible to call sbt with something like:

```
sbt test guava:14.0
sbt test guava:13.0
...
```

Answer (score 4):

You should check this link: [Custom test configuration](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Detailed-Topics/Testing#custom-test-configuration)

I know you don't want to do tests but as you can see, we can create different SBT configuration.
You will probably be able to take inspiration of the following, and be able to create configurations and tasks so that you can run:

- guava13:compile
- guava14:compile
- guava13:test
- guava14:test

And you can perhaps try to add the dependencies as follow:

```
libraryDependencies += "com.google.guava" % "guava" % "13.0" % "guava13"
libraryDependencies += "com.google.guava" % "guava" % "14.0" % "guava14"
```

So that the dependency is scoped to the guava version configuration you use.

Never done this, can't be sure :)

You can also add [cross-build](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Detailed-Topics/Cross-Build)

Nice library idea by the way.

Comment: Thanks, that is a possible workaround. Maybe you wanna update your link to http://www.scala-sbt.org